# Attempting to cleanse old users from a SQL Server Management Studio database. Which can i delete?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

So, I've recently started a placement working on a database management team. And I've been asked to cleanse an old database of users who should no longer have access/ defunct accounts of old employees or poorly named users.
However, upon inspection of some of these users, some have 'Owned Schemas' and some have login names which have to be from a select list, however, this name isn't on the list. Anyone know how to know whether I can delete them if they have owned schemas? Some seem to be schemas named after themselves. It seems to be very poorly, maintained. Hence the revamp.

Comment: You should find out if there's any object being owned by the schema. If not I think we can drop the schema first or change schema owner to self if it's system schema and then drop the user.

Comment: ```ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[schemaname] TO [dbo]``` will make dbo the schema owner and you should be able to delete the login without issue. If any happen to be a database owner, this will alter that: ```ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[database] to sa;```